# What is the exception that should be thrown when user input is blank?

Tags: error-handling, try-catch, tcl, throw

I've been searching for some time now, and I'm sure I've missed it, is there any documentation that states what should be thrown when a value is incorrect/blank?

For example, `Python` has [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) and the documentation clearly states when to use it.

I have the following method:

```
proc getJobinfo {question} {
    puts -nonewline "$question: "
    flush stdout
    gets stdin answer
    set cleanedanswer [string trim [string totitle $answer]]
    if {$cleanedanswer eq ""} {
       # What error should be thrown?
    }
    return $cleanedanswer
}
```

I've searched [`throw`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/throw.htm), [`error`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/error.htm), and [`catch`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/catch.htm), but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl doesn't have a pre-defined hierarchy of exceptions. The throw command takes 2 arguments: `type` is a list of words; and `message` is an error message for humans.

You could do something like

```
proc getJobinfo {question} {
    ...
    if {$cleanedanswer eq ""} {
        throw {Value Empty} "Please provide a suitable answer."
    } elseif {[string length $cleanedanswer] < 5} {
        throw {Value Invalid} "Your answer is too short."
    } else ...
    return $cleanedanswer
}
```

If you want to trap that error:

```
try {
    set answer [getJobinfo "What is the answer to this question"]
} trap {Value *} msg {
    puts "Value Error: $msg"
}
```

---

`throw` and `try` interact via the `type` words of the `throw` call. We throw "Value Empty" or "Value Invalid". In the trap, we match `Value` exactly, but we won't match `*` exactly. In hindsight the `*` should not be there.
The [`try`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/try.htm) manpage is not super clear at first read:

> **trap** *pattern* *variableList* *script*
>
> > This clause matches if the evaluation of *body* resulted in an error and the prefix of the **-errorcode** from the interpreter's status dictionary is equal to the *pattern*. The number of prefix words taken from the **-errorcode** is equal to the list-length of *pattern*, and inter-word spaces are normalized in both the **-errorcode** and *pattern* before comparison.

*pattern* is not a pattern in the `regexp` or `string match` sense: it's a list of words that is matched one-by-one with the list of words thrown in the try *body*.

The `try` can be implemented with multiple traps to have cascading "catches":

```
try {
    set answer [getJobinfo "What is the answer to this question"]

} trap {Value Empty} msg {
    do something specific here

} trap {Value Invalid} msg {
    do something specific here

} trap {Value} msg {
    do something general for some other "throw {Value anything} msg"

} on error e {
    this can be default catch-all for any other error

} finally {
    any cleanup code goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is the use of the `*` in the `trap` documented anywhere?

Comment: There's a little bit of hierarchy, in that `POSIX` is the prefix used for things coming from the OS and `TCL` is for errors originating in Tcl's implementation. Apart from that… the world is open to code authors. I guess it's probably a good idea to use your package name first if you're writing a package?

Comment: @donal, is there a full list of "core" error codes documented anywhere?